# Special Characters in URL query string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, url, query-string

I have a situation where the user is able to enter any characters they want in a URL query string.

Example:

http://localhost/default.aspx?ID=XXXX

http://localhost/default.aspx?ID=&XXXX

http://localhost/default.aspx?ID=#XXXX

The web page must accept the ID parameter as it is no matter what the characters are. However certain special characters such as ampersand(&) and pound(#) creates problems. How can I accept them as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user is entering the query string, they must properly encode the query string first.  If you are creating the query string yourself, such as from a form submission, you will need to use a URL encode method.

Comment: Is there no control that I can add on the web page side where I can interpret special characters such as ampersand(&) as just any ordinary character?

Comment: I think your only choice would be to iterate through all parameters, assuming that ID is the only one you expect.  So if the user enters ?ID=123&456.  Then see what it gives you, the servlet API may only give you one parameter ID with the value 123.  But it may give you a second parameter 456, in which case you can append them together.  This is really a bad solution though as it may be out of order when you iterate through.  The best thing would be to change your requirements because the technology does not support it the way they want it to work.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
encodeURIComponent(uri)
```

Where `uri` is the component after the `?ID=`

Answer (score 1):

Encode your URL [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

**Edit:** following your comment, you want to get query String value of `ID`

```
 String id = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

Comment: In my case the user enters the URL in the address bar. What I need to do is get just the ID entered by the user. How can I do this without having any control towards the URL but only the query string?

Comment: but in that case ID will be an empty string in a situation where ID=&XXXX when what I really want is ID to equal "&XXXX"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
userinput = escape(userinput)
```

then, in PHP:

```
$userinput = urldecode($_GET['id'])
```

or in JS:

```
userinput = unescape(userinput)
```